# Need a way to set variables of a string using an array

Tags: javascript

My question is exactly as described above. I have some code below that defines the variables set in the array. The code that is already there just gets rid of the area in the textbox where you define the variable so that you just get the answer. You can just define the variables or you can write [simp] after defining the variables to get the simplified answer, rather than just having the variables swapped. For example, I want you to be able to write 1+a[a=1] in the textbox, and you to get 1+1 in the text below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PlayBox</title>
            <style>
                textarea {
                    resize: none;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100px;
                }
                body{
                    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
                    background-color: white;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <textarea id="input"></textarea>
            <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
            <p id="output"></p>
            <script>
                function run() {
                    var input = document.getElementById('input').value 
                    var simpPositive = input.search('[simp]')
                    var doctorPositive = input.search('[doctor]')
                    var defineVarPositive = input.search(/\[\D\=\d/)
                    if ((simpPositive > -1) & (defineVarPositive < 0)) {
                        var newInput1 = input.replace('[simp]', '').replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(")
                        var simp = eval(newInput1)
                        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp
                    }
                    if (doctorPositive > -1) {}
                    if (defineVarPositive > -1) {
                        var findMultVar = input.split('[')
                        var elem = findMultVar[1];
                        var fixFindMultVar = elem.substring(0, elem.length -1)
                        var ffmvarr = fixFindMultVar.split(';')//array here
                        var replaceletter = input.split('[')[0]//need more code here to change the variables using the array
                        console.log(replaceletter)
                        if (simpPositive > -1) {
                            var deleteSimp = replaceletter.replace('[simp]', '')
                            var newInput2 = deleteSimp.replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(")
                            var simp = eval(newInput2)
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = replaceletter
                        }
                    }
                    if ((simpPositive < 0) & (defineVarPositive < 0) & (doctorPositive < 0)) {
                        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'error: no modifiers found';
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your trying to use `split` to solve this problem. Though a solution would be possible in theory, it would be quite messy. It is much easier solved simply using string matching & replacement as you've done elsewhere in the code already.

Below, is a simple solution that will search for all the variable assignments (i.e. `[variable=value]`) and then perform a global find-and-replace on the `input`. Finally, the code removes all the variable assignments, giving you the desired result.

It should work for any amount of variable assignments, as well as any amount of variable uses (thanks to the global replacement).

```
for (const match of input.match(/(\[\D\=\d\])/g)) {
  const name = match[1]
  const val = match[3];
  input = input.replace(new RegExp(name, 'g'), val);
}
input = input.replace(/\[.+?\]/g, '');
```

NOTE: I'm not sure of your full requirement - but at the moment your initial code (and hence the code above) accounts for a single character variable name and a single digit value; which is very easily adapted to suit a more general use case.